# JSON schema is incorrect

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm making a JSON schema and I'm using https://tonicdev.com/npm/ajv to validate a schema against some data.
I'm not able to post code here due to confidentiality of the company, so I'll try to describe the problem:

I have 3 input fields, the first is a selector (string), the second an operator dropdown(equal, not equal, in, ni, etc) and the third is an input field that contains a value.

The idea is to have this structure "selector: operator: value ". 
To clarify, say we have this JSON and imagine we have three variables selector, operator and value as schema (the idea is to get those values from the input fields mentioned above and create the schema).

```
const currentData = {
    "properties": {
         "id": "one",
         "string": 'some string...'
    }
}
```

and I need to define the schema

```
const schema = {
    "properties": {
       [selector]: {"type": "string"},
       [operator]: {"type":"string"},
       [value]: {"type": string}
     }   
}
```

If I complete the fields with say (selector: id Operator: Equal value: "one") it should pass the validation, but if I say (selector: id  Operator: Equal value: 1) it should not pass.

This schema is wrong. Any ideas of how to define it?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for ajv schema mentions specific details about how to do this with [patterns](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#pattern).

Hope that helps!